# Does mvn deploy also install/copy the pom.xml in to the remote repo?

Tags: java, maven

Does mvn deploy also install/copy the pom.xml in to the remote repo?

From my understanding `mvn deploy` installs or copies the artifacts in to the remote repo. What I am not sure is - apart from the `.jar` what other files does maven copy to the repo?

Can I control what files are copied/installed and what are not to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

Maven copies the POM to the local or remote repository.

Additionally, checksum files are generated. If applicable, `sources` and `javadoc` JARs are uploaded, too. These two extra files do not need to be uploaded.

The POM needs to uploaded, though. A JAR without a POM cannot be accessed by Maven.

Comment: Excellent. So I got to deploy the pom.xml for sure. Fine